# DeepLinks work, but when I type the website hostname I get a blank screen

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I successfully configured deeplinks for android and IOs and I have a correct .well-known/assetlinks.json like this :

```
[{
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
    "target" : { "namespace": "android_app", "package_name": "com.xxxx.now",
                 "sha256_cert_fingerprints": ["XX:XX:XX"] }
  }]
```

Moreover, on the app, I have configured the manifest with :

```
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xx.xxxxxx.com" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Finally, in the script I have this :

```
  initializeDeepLinks(): void {
App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
  this.zone.run(() => {
    // Example url: https://beerswift.app/tabs/tab2
    // slug = /tabs/tab2
    const slug = data.url.split(".com").pop();
    if (slug) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(slug);
    }
    // If no match, do nothing - let regular routing 
    // logic take over
  });
});
```

}

Now, when I click facebook login, after the login it comes back to the app so it works great.

However, if I go to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), if I have the app installed, I get a blank screen. If I uninstall the app, it works again.

Has anyone had this issue before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just if anyone has the same problem, it Wasn't because of deeplinks, it was the Localnotification.channel not working on mobile version.

To debug in dev mode, I suggest you run chrome and activate mobile web and pick the phone you want and it will behave like if you were using the phone (in case you use platform.is like I do)